# Display second variable different in ggplot geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-bar

I want to treat the display of my second variable (legend, In or out) different than the first variable (x-axis, Reason). So, in stead of having the fill of the Out category blue, I want it to be transparant, but with a stripe pattern.

Also, in the grey area I do want to display the absolute numbers, whereas in the now blue area, I want to show the percentages.

Does anyone know how to adjust the qualities of the graph display for the levels of the second variable seperately?

Here's my data

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
dataframe <- data.frame(status = c("In", "In", "In", "Out", "Out", "Out"),
                    category = c("Before", "Because of", "After", "Before", "Because of", "After"),
                    number = c(100000, 95000, 80000, 15000, 20000, 30000),
                    perc = c(0.9, 0.83, 0.76, 0.09, 0.16, 0.23))

bar <- ggplot(data = dataframe,
          aes(x = category,
              y = number,
              fill = status))

bar +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
       colour = "black",
       width = 1) +
 labs(x = "Reason") +
 labs(y = "Number") +
 labs(fill = "In or out") +
 scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Before", "Because of", "After")) +
 geom_text(aes(label=number), vjust = -2) +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c('light grey', '#0099FF')) +
 background_grid(major = "y", minor = "none")
```

Comment: Stripe patterns are difficult in `ggplot`. You can have a look at the [EggHatch function](https://hubrishubrishubris.wordpress.com/2018/01/12/egghatch-a-function-for-easy-pattern-addition-in-ggplot2-bar-plots/). But I don't know if it supports colors or line widths, so you may have to add these yourself.

Comment: Also note that stripes will affect the perception of the height of the bar, and are therefore often warned against.